# k8s_api connection time out in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, urllib3

I wanted to list the namespaces present in a cluster using Kubernetes API i.e. using the `list_namespace` method.

When I run the below-mentioned code from my Linux machine it works fine.

I created a Jenkins pipeline job and calling the python file as below its throwing Connection Timeout error.

If I do a `kubectl get ns` in same Jenkins file I am getting the output.

I thought of proxies are not allowing it. But could not find how to fix it.

My Python code:

```
config.load_kube_config(os.environ['KUBE_CONFIG'])
v1_api = client.CoreV1Api()
api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()

try: 
    api_response = api_instance.list_namespace(limit="1")
    pprint(api_response)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->list_namespace: %s\n" % e)

sys.exit("EXITING")
```

Command I ran:

```
export KUBE_CONFIG=${env.WORKSPACE}/.kube/kube_config
python36 listns.py
```

Error:

> WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)': /api/v1/namespaces?limit=1
>
> Exception when calling CoreV1Api->list_namespace:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXXXXXX', port=xxxx): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /api/v1/namespaces?limit=1 (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]
>   Connection timed out',))

Answer (score 0):

Got a fix by passing the proxy using Configuration class:

```
configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.proxy='http://www-proxy-<myproxyserver>'

api_instance = kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration)
```